# Compare Worksheets Vlookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am using Microsoft Office 2010. I have 5 worksheets.

Worksheet 1: Provided 
Worksheet 2: WL Tool Summary
Worksheet 3: Salesforce
Worksheet 4: Pipeline 
Worksheet 5: Combined

Typically, I get a list of 20+ names. I copy and paste those 20+ names in the provided tab.

Then I pull names from WL Tool Summary. I copy and paste 30+ names into that worksheet.

Same thing with Salesforce/Pipline.

Then I change the color of each text in each worksheet: so provided could be blue, WL tool could be green etc. I copy all the tabs into combined and I look for matches.

I know there is a way to have excel compare these values for me and spit out the result in the "Combined" tab. I tried to write the formula myself but it didn't work

=VLOOKUP("*"&Provided!A2&"*",$A$2:$A$30,Combined!C2,0)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide some sample data so we can better help you.

Comment: Ok Worksheet 1: Google, Apple, IBM, Alibaba Worksheet 2: IBM, Walmart, Target, Sony Worksheet 3: Alibaba, Netflix, AT&T, IBM Worksheet 4: Apple, Google, Natures Bounty, Miller Coors. Worksheet 5: I would like the formula to just say Match = Google, IBM, Apple etc. Ideally, it would be better if the formula said Google match found on Worksheet 4 etc.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend start naming the ranges of data in each sheet, for example List1, List2, List3 and List4. Once you have done it, You can use following formula in worksheet5:

=A2&" Match Found in"&IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2,List1,0)>0," Worksheet1  ",""),"")&IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2,List2,0)>0," Worksheet2 ",""),"")&IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2,List3,0)>0," Worksheet3 ",""),"")&IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2,List4,0)>0," Worksheet4 ",""),"")

replace A2 with cell in which you have the name of the company you want to compare. And you can replace Worksheet1,Worksheet2,Worksheet3,Worksheet4 with the text/name you want to display.